# When I build my project on xcode iphone simulator crashes

Tags: xcode, debugging, ios4, ios-simulator, cocos2d-iphone

It also  gives me a message at the bottom left of xcode saying Debugging Terminated. 
There are no errors in the code just the iphone simulator crashes when I build my file. It is the first xcode project I've done from scratch (cocos2d template) just some more info to take into consideration. Thanks. Cheers.

Comment: This could be anything. You should supply some code and more detail about exactly what you have done. Just as a general tip, rather than using Build and Run, you should use Build and Debug and when the app crashes, look at the Debugger window and on the left side panel, it'll show you the different classes that were being run. Click the top most black one (Not grayed out) which should be a class that you wrote and it'll show you the line that it crashed on. You can also look on the right hand side of the Debugger window to see the values of different variables to assist in your debugging.

Comment: the simulator crashes? Or the app? If the simulator crashes the only thing that helps in my experience is a reboot and a prayer.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting build target to iOS 4.2. (not 4.3)